# Hbase ResultScanner.next() take to long to respond at first time

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I'm kind of new to Hbase and my following problems might seem silly! I apologize in advance :)

We have a use case where we need to store some large data in Hbase, each row is almost 30MB, and we store it in 6 columns of 5MB each and 2 columns for some metadata all in one column family. We have two types of data and we use Hbase as **some big queue**!

We have created two tables in Hbase, named TableA and TableB. We must insert data (from type A or B) and we have a pull function that should get one row (of type A or B), return it and delete it from table.

We have three clusters nodes with 4GB RAM and sufficient storage.

For that job, in Java, I make a `ResultScanner`, get the key of the first row, and retrieve whole row with `Get`, something like below

```java
Scan scanA = new Scan();
scanA.addColumn(familyByteArray, oneSmallColumnByteArray);
ResultScanner scanner = tblA.getScanner(scanA);

// The big problem is here, this blows region servers and takes too long 
// to respond
Result r = scanner.next();

// no problem here
Get get = new Get(r.getRowKey());
r = tblA.get(get);
```

The first time of `scanner.next()` call blows regionServers (even stored data is small almost (8k rows)) and by increasing `hbase.rpc.timeout` I prevent from `SocketTimeoutException`, but regionServers still going down in first `next()` sometimes.

First, `scanner.next()` takes for example 60 seconds but next `scanner.next()`s answer quickly (like 1 second).

As I mentioned before I don't care about which row returns, I just want to get one row and return it.

Do you have any idea on how to increase the speed of `scanner.next()` and prevent it from killing regionServers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you mean by 3 cluster? I think what you meant to say is 3 node cluster.

Now as for the solution 4Gb (is it total memory of Node?) ram is not at all sufficient for Hbase unless it's a local VM.

Ideal heap allocated for HBase should not be less than 8Gb.
Now i would suggest some modification to the code

- Add a scan cache to the scanner ideally it should be around 200 to 750 but in your case start with a lower value
- Enable compression on HBase table
- If in future you have sufficient processing power and memory try Endpoint Coprocessor
- Check if there is no major compaction is happening on the table. Let it finish then try to fire a scan
- Enable bloom filters on your HBase tables
- Last but not the least don't forget to close result scanner